# How to write script for automatic joomla installation in webhost

Tags: shell-script, mysql

I want to create a script in Linux that automatically downloads the latest Joomla from their website and then installs it to the specified user. Is it possible in a shell script?

I don't know how it will find the latest Joomla and how it will work, but I want to know if it's possible

Comment: It's certainly possible; are you looking for actual code?

Comment: that will be **excellent**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course it's possible. Any series of things you could do on a command line (and many that aren't feasible there) can be scripted. You will need to find some page or directory that has an identifiable link to the latest version. First parse so you know either the version or have a link to the latest file, then download it, then script out whatever steps need to be taken to install it.

Comment: can u give me some sample code

Comment: No sorry I don't have time to write other people scripts that do their jobs for them. I can tell you it's possible and give you an outline, but basically scripting just involves writing down all the steps that you would normally do by hand and chaining them together. There are lots of bash and other shell scripting guides available on the web. This is a QnA site not mechanical turk, on demand tutorial or contract job board. If you get stuck on any specific steps feel free to ask specific questions.